# Не работает POST запрос в Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, http, rest, spring-mvc

Пытаюсь написать простое crud RESTful приложение на Spring MVC.

В Postman посылаю POST запрос на

```
http://localhost:8080/persons/new
```

и получаю 400 ошибку.

Пытался в дебаге посмотреть доходил вообще запрос до контроллера, все тщетно, такое чувство что запрос вообще не доходит.

Хотя GET запрос отрабатывает нормально.

Код конфигурации DispatcherServlet'а:

```
package Configs.SpingWebConfig;

import Configs.DataConfig.AppConfig;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringServletDispatcherConfiguration extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{AppConfig.class};
    }

    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

Код имплементации WebMvcConfigurer:

```
package Configs.DataConfig;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"Configs", "Controllers", "DAO", "Service"})
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public AppConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Код controller'а:

```
package Controllers;

import Model.Person;
import Service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @GetMapping("/persons")
    public List<Person> getAllPerson(){
        List<Person> personsList = personService.getAllPerson();

        return personsList;
    }

    @GetMapping("/persons/{id}")
    public Person getPersonById(@PathVariable long id){
        Person person = personService.getPersonById(id);

        return person;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/persons/delete")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deletePerson(@RequestParam Person person){
        personService.deletePerson(person);

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    @PostMapping("/persons/new")
    public ResponseEntity<Person> createNewPerson(@RequestParam Person person){
        personService.addNewPerson(person);

        return new ResponseEntity<Person>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PostMapping("/persons/update/{id}")
    public Person updatePerson(@RequestParam Person person){
        personService.updatePerson(person);
        Person updatedPerson = personService.getPersonById(person.getId());
        return updatedPerson;
    }
}
```

Файл POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>owl.home</groupId>

  <artifactId>TestQuestion</artifactId>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <name>TestQuestion Maven Webapp</name>

  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>9.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.kemitix/sqlite-dialect -->
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>TestQuestion</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Скрины Postman'а

[image: Тот самый POST запрос]
[image: Заголовки POST'а]

[image: GET]
[image: Заголовки GET'а]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [POST запрос: "status": 415, "error": "Unsupported Media Type"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1180439/post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-status-415-error-unsupported-media-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запрос доходит до контроллера и более того сообщает, что вы не передали ему обязательный параметр запроса `person`

Насколько могу понять, вам следует использовать не `@RequestParam`, а `@RequestBody`, поскольку вы передаете JSON в теле запроса, а не `multipart/form-data`

**попробуйте так**

```
    @PostMapping("/persons/new")
    public ResponseEntity<Person> createNewPerson(@RequestBody Person person){
        personService.addNewPerson(person);

        return new ResponseEntity<Person>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо